# How to prove a convergence of a Taylor series to $f$

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {f^{(n)}}(0) x^k /k!$ converges to $(1+x)^p$ in the interval (-1,1) and $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

use the definition of limit 
and prove that
$$
o(x^n)=f-\sum_0^\infty f^{(n)}(0)/k!
$$ can be "ignored"
or you can look for any analysis course